# How to work with DESLib in Wolfram SystemModeler 4.1

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, modelica, systemmodeler

As a newbie in System Modeler 4.1 I am interested in queuing systems and found the DESLib, especially the ArenaLib. Unfortunately DESLib 1.7 seems not to work within this environment (version problem?).

Does anyone know how to download, install and test DESLib?

regards
Volker

Comment: Can you specify where you download DESLib 1.7 from? The one I see on GitHub is version 1.6.x and dependent on the old Modelica 2.2 standard library.

Comment: I got it from http://www.euclides.dia.uned.es/. UNED is the Universidad Nacional de Educacion a Distancia. They provide the versions
DESLib 1.6.2 (on Modelica 2.2) and
DESLib 1.7 (on Modelica 3.2)
Volker

Comment: Also ask here: [Mathematica Stack Exchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There are several issues with the DESLib version 1.6.2 and 1.7 which is why this has not been listed yet on modelica.org/libraries. I've contacted the author about this but he doesn't have time to look into it.

Comment: Does anyone know an alternative for modeling queuing systems?